# How to add host to a Carrierwave url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave on a Document model.

```
class Document
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader 
end
```

and am trying to send an email with document as attachment

```
class DocumentMailer
  def distribute(recipient, document)
    filename = document.file.file.original_filename
    attachments[ filename ] = File.read(document.file.url)
    mail( 
      to: receipient.email, 
      subject: "Document attached"
    )
  end
end
```

In tests, the Mailer is raising an error

```
Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/document/file/2/my_attachment.jpg
```

I can resolve this error in the test suite by calling `path` instead of `url` in DocumentMailer, which returns the full filesystem path

```
attachments[ filename ] = File.read(document.file.path)
# /Users/AHH/code/myapp/tmp/uploads/document/file/2/my_attachment.jpg
```

However, this causes the method to fail in production. Carrierwave is using fog to store files on S3, and so I need the full url to assign an attachment to DocumentMailer.

Why do the tests fail when using `file.url`? I assume it is because the url has no host. So how to I ensure that Carrierwave applies a host to `file.url` in the test environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of the way that you store files in development/test versus production due to the fact that `url` is actually a URL in production, probably to an S3 host, but locally it's a path to a file, relative to wherever you've specified uploads to be stored. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like CarrierWave has a graceful way of handling this, at least so far as I've seen, so I ended up doing something like this in our spec helper:

```
config.before do
  allow_any_instance_of(DocumentUploader).to receive(:url) do |uploader|
    uploader.path
  end
end
```